# how to get residuals from an autoregressive model by hand

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive-models, vector-auto-regression

I would like to know how to calculate residuals from a fitted AR model by hand. Now I can use `stats::ar` to fit an autoregresive model and and get the residuals by from `$resid` of the fitted model, however I would like to be able to calculate these myself given the estimated AR parameters. So I would like to have a function that takes the estimated AR parameters from the ar model and a time-series and returns the residuals or a time-series with the auto-correlation removed.

My ultimate goal is to be able to estimate AR coefficients on one dataset and apply them to another, or to try to remove slightly different AR coefficients from the same time-series.

So for example here I would lieke to be able to reproduce the same `ar_model$resid` data by applying the estimated coefs to the original multivariate `usconsumption` timeseries.

```
> library(fpp)
> ar_model <- ar(usconsumption, aic=FALSE, order.max=1)
> ar_model$ar
, , consumption

  consumption    income
1   0.3088803 0.5627686

, , income

  consumption     income
1  0.08269438 -0.2310507

> head(ar_model$resid)
         consumption     income
1970 Q1          NA         NA
1970 Q2  -0.2363646  1.0249511
1970 Q3   0.1294457  1.0084068
1970 Q4  -1.1150108 -0.9913129
1971 Q1   1.5423841  1.5613124
1971 Q2  -0.2947244  0.3983440
```

I tried to use `timsac::mfilter` function, but I wasn't able to get anything close to the original `ar` residuals.

Comment: Luke, read the code.

Comment: @IRTFM yeah i tried that as well, it seems that code is above my level. I think this is the code https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/ar.R

Comment: My understanding is that SO Qs are supposed to be discrete. You apparently want us to examine large blocks of code in two different packages (stats and timesac) and resolve differences in their output. (It may be that these two packages have different goals and methods, but that would best be resolved by people who are familiar with both packages. Perhaps a domain expert can be found at stats.stackexchange.com or https://quant.stackexchange.com/ . )Voting to close as lacking sufficient focus.

Comment: @IRTFM I think that asking how to calculate residuals in code is totally within the scope of SO, there is plenty of similar questions bud regarding different libraries and models, since those questions are not being closed, this one should not be either. There is also plenty of questions about autoregression or the stats package. I don't want people to examine large blocks of code of different packages. If that's what you would need to do to answer this question that just mean it's not a question for you, but that doesn't mean it is not within scope

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code to try to answer your question.  It will multiply the AR coefficients by the lagged values according to this formula from the `ar` help page.

Unfortunately, the result is not exactly correct :(  My calculation of the predicted values is not the same as `fitted(model)`.

Although this does not answer your question, I will post it here in case other users are able identify what's wrong wit this code, or use it as a template for a full solution.

*formula*:
x
t
​
−μ=a
1
​
(x
t−1
​
−μ)+⋯+a
p
​
(x
t−p
​
−μ)+e
t
​

```r
library(fpp, quietly = TRUE)

# fit
model <- ar(usconsumption, aic = FALSE, order.max = 1)

# initialize
pred <- matrix(nrow = nrow(usconsumption), ncol = 2)
colnames(pred) <- colnames(usconsumption)

# predict
for (i in 2:nrow(usconsumption)) {
  pred[i, "consumption"] <- model$x.mean["consumption"] + sum((usconsumption[i-1, ] - model$x.mean) * model$ar[, ,"consumption"])
  pred[i, "income"] <- model$x.mean["income"] + sum((usconsumption[i-1, ] - model$x.mean) * model$ar[, ,"income"])
}

# compare
head(fitted(model))
#>         getResponse(object).consumption getResponse(object).income
#> 1970 Q1                              NA                         NA
#> 1970 Q2                       0.6912944                  0.7115085
#> 1970 Q3                       0.7452274                  0.3364742
#> 1970 Q4                       0.8424964                  0.6631670
#> 1971 Q1                       0.3498029                  0.4041199
#> 1971 Q2                       1.2081025                  1.0924131

head(pred)
#>      consumption    income
#> [1,]          NA        NA
#> [2,]   0.5760684 0.7801837
#> [3,]   1.2252548 0.4806877
#> [4,]   1.1345370 0.6058726
#> [5,]  -0.1613336 0.8975607
#> [6,]   1.7980539 0.5466365
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>